# A Place for Large Creatures

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Root beer tree top (3)
>   Second half popular chocolate wafer (3)
>   Chemical engineer cv (3)
>   First tough bite returned pale(3)

Not a very tough or clever one, but hopefully sound. The answers combined explain the (not cryptic) title.

Comment: These are not cryptic clues; apart from the last one they have only one "route" to the answer rather than the two (definition and wordplay) required for a cryptic clue. That's not necessarily a problem; note that Sconibulus was able to solve them all reasonably quickly, and the way in which they are combined provides the missing cross-checking. But it does mean that the cryptic-clues tag is of doubtful application here.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, heard and noted. The other one that might have qualified you pointed out a missing operation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root beer tree top (3)

> references Sassafrass. Making the first three letters SAS

Second half popular chocolate wafer (3)

> referencing Kit-Kat, so next three letters KAT

Chemical engineer cv (3)

> Major often displayed in course books as CHE, imagine it would show up that way on a CV too.

First tough bite returned pale(3)

> least confident of this clue, but pale and WAN are synonyms, and that makes the final word work.

Making the final word

> Saskatchewan, a reasonably large, relatively sparsely populated province in Canada, home to such large animals as Moose, Bear, and Bison

Comment: Perhaps "First tough bite ..." is GNAW without its first letter, backwards. Though I don't quite see what indicates that the first letter is to be *removed*.

Comment: How is Saskatchewan a place for large creatures?? Isn't it only a small city in Canada??

Comment: @Sid It's a reasonably sized province in Canada, actually, I think it has Moose and Bears and stuff.

Comment: So, what Gareth said about gnaw (and the unintentional absence of _removed_ letter) was supposed to be the idea. I was trying to make a Sasquatch/Bigfoot reference, but Saskatchewan isn't as well known for Bigfoot sightings as I thought. Good work Sconibulus. (oh, and after further reading I was _not_ thinking the province was named after Sasquatch or vice-versa :)